# php ldap return array values inside a loop

Tags: php, arrays

Using a PHP script, I am pulling data from a database.  In the column `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` is an array, as the values in one column are listed: `FacultyActive|StudentArchived`.

If anyone can point me in the right code direction to returning these results, I would be super appreciative!  Right now, obviously, I'm only returning `Array` for this column.

I'll take any help even it is "look over here moron!"

Thanks in advance!

**See code below**

```
for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
{
    if(@$info[$i]['mail']['0']) 
    {
        $name = $info[$i]['cn']['0'];
        $email =  $info[$i]['mail']['0'];
        $firstname =  $info[$i]['givenname']['0'];
        $lastname = $info[$i]['sn']['0'];
        $department =  $info[$i]['department']['0'];
        $title = $info[$i]['title']['0'];

        $physicalDeliveryOfficeName[] = array(
            "status" => $info[$i]['physicalDeliveryOfficeName']['0']
        );

        //write data to see what will appear in csv
        echo $firstname.",".$lastname.",".$email.",".$physicalDeliveryOfficeName."<br />";
        //$data element below writes to csv
        $data = $firstname.",".$lastname.",".$email.",".$physicalDeliveryOfficeName."\n" ; //////   the complied line that gets written to csv file
        write_email($data);
    }
}
```

In both the display results page, a CSV column for `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` I would like to see this data `FacultyActive|StudentArchived` in that column

Comment: 'status' => implode('|',$info[$i]['pdonType']['0']); With out the data posted this is my guess.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Unfortunately I am still returning "Array"